# Java Swing - KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

How can I know when the key typed change my text? Or if the key is a char?

Comment: What text?  Is it in a text field, text area, etc?  How are you listening?  Do you only care if the key pressed is in a text area, or only if it isn't?  A little more about what you are trying to accomplish from listening for the key press would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface **KeyListener** contain three methods:

void keyTyped(KeyEvent)
void keyPressed(KeyEvent)
void keyReleased(KeyEvent)

So, if you get the char in the **KeyEvent** object like:

```
if ("a".equals(KeyEvent.getKeyChar()))
    System.out.println("It's a letter")
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want to know wether typing a specific key actually prints a char or is some "invisible" control character or something:

in this case you can check the typed key in the KeyEvent which gets passed into the implemented methods of the KeyListener:

this quick example should work, although i didnt test it. It constructs a new String on the char returned by the KeyEvent, than invokes the length() method to chekc if the char created a readable character in the String. kinda hacky but i hope you get the gist of it

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
    if (new String(ke.getKeyChar()).length() == 0){
        // do something important...
    }
}
```

alternativley you can use `ke.getKeyCode()` and check vs the static fields in KeyEvent (VK_F12,VK_ENTER...)

check here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: It doesn't work! :(
When I create the string after backspace, the value is "\b", what means length equals 1.

Comment: reading the javadoc yielded that getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED should work...

Answer (score 1):

You need a document listener. See the oracle docs for more information: [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)