# Java is not picking up keypresses?

Tags: java, swing, overriding, public, keylistener

I have a program which produces a JFrame and then a JPanel on top of it. For the program, I have tried implementing the KeyListener and then adding the methods (for both components), but the program does not pick any of my key strokes up. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is my code. It is a part of the class which creates the JFrame. It still does not pick up the press of the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.out.println("Hi");

    }else{
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

Comment: without the code, it is impossible to say

Comment: The Component with the keylistener needs to have the focus...

Comment: Are you sure the event doesn't get called?

Comment: are you trying to catch event corresponding to TAB key?

Comment: @MarkusKreth How would you set the focus of the JFrame?

Answer (score 3):

Without your code, all I can tell you is that usually when people ask this they don't know that the interface `KeyListener` contain three methods as Agusti-N states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355574/java-swing-keylistener/3355666#3355666):

```
void keyTyped(KeyEvent)
void keyPressed(KeyEvent)
void keyReleased(KeyEvent)
```

If you use `keyTyped` and you are using `event.getKeyCode()` to check for the character entered, this will not work. You should use `getKeyChar()` for `keyTyped` and `getKeyCode()` for `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`. Otherwise you'll get `null`.
You should only use this if you do not have any other alternative, in most cases you want to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Ah, never knew about this difference between `code` and `character` in this context.

Comment: Also, you may well have forgotten to register the KeyListener with the JPanel.  Use panel.addKeyListener( listener ).

Comment: @Mr D did you refer to the part of the [`KeyEvent` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()) which says "For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED."

Comment: Yes, actually I found out not long ago when i was working on some javafx project and I read the NetBeans tip for it