# Pressed button as a hotkey

Tags: java

I'm trying to make something like hotkey textbox. User presses <kbd>F11</kbd> / <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> / any key and it appears in the box.
I did it this way:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    textField_1.setText(String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()));
}
```

but it doesn't work for the Fs, caps lock etc. (what is obvious, because those aren't chars).
How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `e.getKeyText()` instead of `e.getKeyChar()` that will return `F1` if the <kbd>F1</kbd> key is presed. Here is the API description:

> **getKeyText**
>
> **public static String getKeyText(int keyCode)**
>
> Returns a String describing the keyCode, such as "HOME", "F1" or "A".
>   These strings can be localized by changing the awt.properties file.
>
> **Returns:** a string containing a text description for a physical key, identified by its keyCode

-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText(int)

**Alternatively:**

You could also use `e.getKeyCode` that will give you the key codes for the various key events identified their corresponding constant values. For instance, e.getKeyCode will return `112` as the value for a key press for <kbd>F1</kbd>, which can be accessed by the constant `VK_F1`. Following is the API Description:

> **getKeyCode**
>
> **public int getKeyCode()**
>   Returns the integer keyCode associated with
>   the key in this event.
>   **Returns:** the integer code for an actual key on
>   the keyboard. (For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED.)

-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode()

And here are the listings for the Key Constants: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying a text field from a key listener, apart from the fact it can cause concurrent modification errors, there's no guarantee in what order the key listeners are notified and the key may be consumed before you. Much better to use a DocumentFilter and KeyBindings - IMHO

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
event.getKeyCode();
```

But in general you should probably use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

As Agusti-N states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355574/java-swing-keylistener/3355666#3355666):

> The interface `KeyListener` contain three methods:
>
> ```
> void keyTyped(KeyEvent)
> void keyPressed(KeyEvent)
> void keyReleased(KeyEvent)
> ```

If you use `keyPressed` and you are using `event.getKeyChar()` to check for the character entered, this will not work. You should use `getKeyChar()` for `keyTyped` and `getKeyCode()` for `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`. Otherwise you'll get `null`.
As stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29).

Comment: the reason is simply because thats [how they coded it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29), nothing in particular as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some research about key bindings.

Comment: Please make sure you properly quote wording that you copy from other sources. I've done this above, but you need to make sure you do this in the future.